# how can I save a file in a diffrent format?

Tags: c#, text, rtf, file-format

I have a quick question, how do you save a file in a different format like in "save as"

so far i got this

```
   private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this saves the file as a text or richtext. 
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = ("RichText*.rtf; )|*.rtf; |TextDocs *.txt;|*.txt");

        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        //this gives the title of the savefiledialog.
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "save file";
        //this prompts the user if they want to overwrite an existing file.
        saveFileDialog1.OverwritePrompt = true;
        //gets the input made by the savefiledialog.
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //saves the file.
            richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName,
                //saves the text in the richbox
                RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

I want to be able to save as ether a rtf or a txt format. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use filename different name and pass it to SaveFile with the read content buffer from origianl file.

Comment: can you give me a example please, I'm still kind of new to C#.

Comment: give a different file name in place of saveFileDialog1.FileName variable when you do saveas kind of operation.

Comment: thanks I got it!  I just can't believe  it was that simple :P